# Roaming Setting not working properly in Office.js

Tags: reactjs, outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am seeing some odd behavior with roaming settings. I can set a roaming setting in memory, notice it changed successfully. Then i navigate to other page, i get updated setting there and that is root url of my application. But when i reload add-in from Ribbon Button again, it loads my root url and it shows me OLD value of roaming setting. Similarly when i restart my Outlook application and load add-in from Ribbon Button, it loads my root url and it shows me NEW value(Which i actually want without restarting outlook application).

How can i get NEW value of Roaming setting without restart my Outlook desktop client again?

On MyPage :

```
window.office.context.roamingSettings.set("ABC","NewValue");
window.office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync();
this.props.router.push("/");
```

On RootURL:

```
var tempVar = window.office.context.roamingSettings.get("ABC");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to restart Outlook or add-in to get updated value from "roamingSettings" object, indeed. As asynchronous nature of "saveAsync" method you need to wait for completion and after redirect to elsewhere ...

```
window.office.context.roamingSettings.set("ABC","NewValue");
window.office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync( function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.error) {
        // well, work with the error? asyncResult.error.message
    } else {
        this.props.router.push("/");
    }
});
```